# page redirecting

Tags: playframework

Based on certain condition in my controller, I want to direct the user to an error page, which I am doing now.

when error page is displayed to user, I want the user to be then redirected to a specific retry page.

Is this the right way to do it using:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.somewhere.com/" />
```

or should i use javascript to do the redirect based on timer?

To get the right url I could put the url in flash scope and read them and place in above string

Comment: Tag your question with propper Play version - [tag:playframework-1.x] or [tag:playframework-2.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you gonna make a redirect from the HTML level, while you can do it without any problems in your controller ? Play 2, Java:

```
public static Result something(){
    if (someCondition){
        return redirect(routes.Application.errorAction());
    }

    return ok("Render here not redirected view...");
}
```

Comment: The html page is going to show user some directive via some graphics which the UI team wants to control and then take the user to secondry retry page. hence this hodge podge work around. Else other option would be a pop up and when user clicks OK on it then redirect them

Comment: Usually I'm doing a redirection first (with the way I posted) and showing the tip AFTER redirect with JS modal or other kind of alert/dialogbox. Thanx to this I have sure that user won't miss the message, which in your case disappears after 3 seconds. I think that if you'll decide to stay with error message BEFORE the redirect you should put it in JS function and wait for client's reaction (ie. for clicking the button "try again").